# How to iterate over JQuery Selector elements and append some Information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this kind of JQuery selector, which selects 15 kinds of html "td" elements in my rendered HTML Dom:

```
var parentElement = jQuery('.myClassSelector').parent();
```

This jQuery gives my the number of all selected elements:

```
var parentElementSize = jQuery('.myClassSelector').parent().size();
```

Now i would like to iterate over the selected elements and append an Informationtext to each element:

```
for(i = 0; i < parentElementSize; i++){
    parentElement[i].append('Some Informationtext to append !!!');          
}
```

But this kind of code doesn´t work. If i use this kind of jQuery Code, the Informationstext will be rendered 15 for each element but i want to render it once for each element

```
jQuery(parentElement).each(function(){          
    $(this).append('Some Informationtext to append !!!');
});
```

How can i solve this problem?

Many Thanks for helping me !

Comment: @AnoopJoshi HTML is not required. The problem is rather obvious.

Comment: @VisioN I'm not sure about this, will parent() return multiple objects?

Comment: What do you want to append, your comments to the answers so far suggest you're missing some important information. I'm down-voting due to the lack of clarity of your question; clarify what you want and I'll reverse that vote.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi *This jQuery gives my the number of all selected elements: ...*: certainly it does.

Comment: **Please provide your HTML;** you do know that the quality of answers you get is commensurate with the quality of background info your provide, right? :)

Comment: @VisioN I dont think so. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/148/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi This is more relevant jsFiddle, as i understand OP's issue: http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/149/  That's said, question is completly unclear to me. So, OP should provide a jsFiddle which makes his issue and expecting result more clear

Comment: @A.Wolff ohh now its ok. I thought about multi level parents only. But OP doesnt have any interest to put his html here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass 2 parameters when using `$.each` with anonymous function.
First is index of element, second is element itself.

```
jQuery(parentElement).each(function(i, item){          
    $(item).append('Some Informationtext to append !!!');
});
```

Comment: Your code rendered 15 'Some InformationText to append' for each Element !!

Comment: And that's exactly what your code suggests you want; what do you *really* want to do?

Comment: No i want to set one text "Some Informationtext to append !!!" for each selected element and not 15 parts of ""Some Informationtext to append !!!" for each selected element.

Comment: This answer is exactly equivalent to what the OP has provided. Therefore there must be something fundamental the OP has not provided, which is key to getting to the root of his problem. `this` and `item` refer to the same element - the current element in the iteration..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop unless you're appending something different to each parent -

```
var parentElement = jQuery('.myClassSelector').parent(); // they're all selected
parentElement.append('Some Informationtext to append !!!'); // add one thing to each of them
```

Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ur93v/ adding a new row to each table row.

```
var parElem = $('.foo').parent();
var newRow = '<td class="bar">bar</td>';
parElem.append(newRow);
```

Comment: Your code rendered 15 'Some InformationText to append' for each Element !

Comment: Unless there is something that we don't know about your code @Marwief this code works properly.

Comment: There's something fundamental the OP has not provided. May be showing us his HTML may be helpful. As it is, **every RIGHT answer is a WRONG answer** :)